# how to get text value of calling <button> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button

I tried following code but no work:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter-new" id="btn_Filter_New">New</button>
 $("btn_Filter_New").click(function ()
 {
      var ButtonText = $(this).val();
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** function. Also use the id selector correctly `#btn_Filter_New`.

```
 $("#btn_Filter_New").click(function () {
      var ButtonText = $(this).text();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

A button doesn't have a value, it has text. So use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. Your selector is wrong as well, add a `#` before `btn-Filter-New` otherwise it will look for a tag like:

```
<btn-Filter-New>
```

If you're feeling frisky here's a way to do it without jQuery.

```
var x = document.getElementById("btn-Filter-New");
x.onclick = function() {
    var buttonText = x.innerHTML;
}
```

This grabs the ID, and assigns an anonymous function to the event `onclick` that sets `buttonText` to the innerHTML value of x.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` works on input elements (or those have `value` attribute). `.text()` does not work on input elements.

`.text()` gets the innerText of the element. So in case of button you need to use `.text()`

Your selector is also wrong. To select element with `id` you need to use `#`

So try this

```
 $("#btn_Filter_New").click(function (){
      var ButtonText = $(this).text();
 }
```