# Jquery: get text from dynamically generated button in new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some dynamically generated content with jquery.

```
<div id="response">
    <button id="high" class="btn-key-main">high</button>
    <button id="last" class="btn-key-main">last</button>
</div>
```

How do I get the content of the button that is clicked (high or last) in a div with id="solution"?
Here's what I tried:

```
$("#response").on("click", 'button.btn-key-main', function() {
    $("#solution").html($(this).val());
});
```

**Solved by @slicedtoad and @smerny**

.val() should've been .html() or .text()

```
$("#solution").html($(this).html());
```

Comment: is `response` also generated? if so you'll have to either add the listener after creating it or use delegation from a parent that exists at load time

Comment: @smerny the response div is not generated/it's already present in the DOM. The id's of the response are dynamically generated though. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Looks like it should work then. Just change val to `text()`

Comment: Okay, I see another problem... try changing `$(this).val()` to `$(this).html()`... or `text()` as I see slicedtoad beat me to this (your buttons do not have values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get text value of calling <button> in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293613/how-to-get-text-value-of-calling-button-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/o4fyqvk7/

```
$("#response").on("click", 'button.btn-key-main', function() {
    $("#solution").html($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: solution was already provided by @slicedtoad, but you get the points

Answer (score 1):

`$('.selector').val` is documented here: http://api.jquery.com/val/

If you want the text of a button use `$('.selector').text()` http://api.jquery.com/text/

Often it's a good idea to add a values to your buttons.
Just use the HTML `value=''` attribute.

Then you can do things like change the visible language on the button without breaking JS.